# Why is this devectorized Julia code over 20x too slow?

Tags: julia

I thought in Julia (unlike in R or Matlab) devectorized code was often faster than vectorized code. But I'm not finding this to be the case. Here's an example:

```
julia> x = Float64[1:10000000];

julia> y = Array(Float64, length(x));

julia> @time for i = 1:length(x) y[i] = exp(x[i]) end;
elapsed time: 7.014107314 seconds (959983704 bytes allocated, 25.39% gc time)

julia> @time y = exp(x);
elapsed time: 0.364695612 seconds (80000128 bytes allocated)
```

Why is the vectorized code so much faster? It looks like the devectorized code is allocating over 10x as much memory. But only a few bytes actually need to be allocated to exponentiate any number of floats. Is there a way to write the devectorized code so that it doesn't allocate so much memory, and thus runs faster than the vectorized code?

Thanks!

Comment: "_I thought ..._" You should always provide some evidence to support claims of this nature.

Comment: Sure, here's a post that demonstrates how much faster devectorized code can be in Julia: http://www.johnmyleswhite.com/notebook/2013/12/22/the-relationship-between-vectorized-and-devectorized-code/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consider the following code snippet:

```
x = Float64[1:10000000];
y = Array(Float64, length(x));
function nonglobal_devec!(x,y)
    for i = 1:length(x) y[i] = exp(x[i]) end
end
function nonglobal_vec(x)
    exp(x)
end
@time nonglobal_devec!(x,y);
@time y = nonglobal_vec(x);
x = Float64[1:10000000];
y = Array(Float64, length(x));
@time for i = 1:length(x) y[i] = exp(x[i]) end
@time y = exp(x)
```

which gives the times

```
A: elapsed time: 0.072701108 seconds (115508 bytes allocated)
B: elapsed time: 0.074584697 seconds (80201532 bytes allocated)
C: elapsed time: 2.029597656 seconds (959990464 bytes allocated, 22.86% gc time)
D: elapsed time: 0.058509661 seconds (80000128 bytes allocated)
```

The odd one out, C, is [due to it operating in the global scope](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/performance-tips/), where type inference doesn't operate, and slower code is generated.

The relative timings between A and B are subject to some variability due to the functions being compiled the first time they are used. If we run it again we get

```
A2: elapsed time: 0.038542212 seconds (80 bytes allocated)
B2: elapsed time: 0.063630172 seconds (80000128 bytes allocated)
```

which makes sense as A2 doesn't allocate memory (that 80 bytes is for the return value of the function), and B2 creates a new vector. Also note that B2 allocates the same amount of memory as D does - the extra the first time was memory allocated for compilation.

Finally, devectorized vs vectorized is a case-by-case basis. For example, if you implemented matrix multiplication naively with for loops, and no cache awareness, you would be likely to be much slower than using the vectorized `A*b` that uses BLAS.

Comment: Thank, Iain, that's a much better answer than mine.

Comment: I'm going to hijack this thread a little to ask if that 80 bytes in A2 is allocated every single time the function is called?  For instance, if that function is in a for loop that calls it 10^5 times, will 80*10^5 bytes be allocated?

Comment: Pretty sure it wouldn't, which is easy to check - its just a REPL thing. Things are weird at the REPL though! If you were to put that command in a loop, at the REPL, I think you'd probably get 80 bytes, which would be the value from the last time around the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Non-constant global variables are slow:

http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/performance-tips/